# Pandas dataframe custom subset

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to perform a set of operations on a particular dataframe. 
The goal of these operations is to create a dataframe which represents a subset of the larger dataframe.
Here is my original dataframe.

```
CARD_NO,CUSTOMER_ID,MODIFIED_DATE,STATUS,LOYALTY
1111111111111111,1111111,2013-09-09 02:59:09,1,0
2222222222222222,2222222,2013-09-08 14:22:11,0,0
3333333333333333,3333333,2013-01-01 11:11:11,1,0
3333333333333333,3333333,2013-01-01 22:22:22,1,0
4444444444444444,4444444,2014-01-01 11:11:11,1,0
4444444444444444,4444444,2014-11-26 04:22:22,0,0
5555555555555555,5555555,2014-10-10 10:10:10,1,0
5555555555555555,5555555,2014-10-10 10:10:10,0,0
6666666666666666,6666666,2014-04-01 14:30:00,1,0
6666666666666666,6666666,2014-04-02 14:30:00,0,0
6666666666666666,6666666,2014-04-03 14:30:00,1,0
7777777777777777,7777777,2014-03-03 00:01:00,0,0
7777777777777777,7777777,2014-03-03 00:02:00,1,0
7777777777777777,7777777,2014-03-03 00:02:01,0,0
```

My goal is to arrive at the following dataframe:

```
CARD_NO,CUSTOMER_ID,MODIFIED_DATE,STATUS,LOYALTY
1111111111111111,1111111,2013-09-09 02:59:09,1,0
2222222222222222,2222222,2013-09-08 14:22:11,0,0
3333333333333333,3333333,2013-01-01 22:22:22,1,0
4444444444444444,4444444,2014-11-26 04:22:22,0,0
5555555555555555,5555555,2014-10-10 10:10:10,1,0
6666666666666666,6666666,2014-04-03 14:30:00,1,0
7777777777777777,7777777,2014-03-03 00:02:01,0,0
```

The logic is as follows:
For each CARD_NO
 - if there is only 1 CARD_NO, keep in dataframe
 - if there are > 1 of the same CARD_NO, check MODIFIED_DATE,
 - if MODIFIED_DATEs are different, take the **most recent**
 - if all MODIFIED_DATES are equal, take whichever row has STATUS = 1

I am able to segregate all of the different cases, but I'm unable to point keep the entire row in the context of dataframe.

This correctly points to the CARD_NOs 11111111 and 22222222.

```
def is_length_one(items):
    return len(items) == 1
print input.groupby('CARD_NO').apply(lambda x: is_length_one(x['MODIFIED_DATE'].values))

CARD_NO
1111111111111111     True
2222222222222222     True
3333333333333333    False
4444444444444444    False
5555555555555555    False
6666666666666666    False
7777777777777777    False
```

This correctly points to the case 55555555, where 2 rows have the same CARD_NO and MODIFIED_DATE but different STATUSES.

```
def all_same(items):    
    return all(x == items[0] for x in items) and len(items) >= 2
print input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False).apply(lambda x: all_same(x['MODIFIED_DATE'].values))

CARD_NO
1111111111111111    False
2222222222222222    False
3333333333333333    False
4444444444444444    False
5555555555555555     True
6666666666666666    False
7777777777777777    False
```

I also have the method for returning the most recent date.

```
def most_recent(items):
return max(items)
print input.groupby('CARD_NO').apply(lambda x: most_recent(x['MODIFIED_DATE'].values))

CARD_NO
1111111111111111    2013-09-09 02:59:09
2222222222222222    2013-09-08 14:22:11
3333333333333333    2013-01-01 22:22:22
4444444444444444    2014-11-26 04:22:22
5555555555555555    2014-10-10 10:10:10
6666666666666666    2014-04-03 14:30:00
7777777777777777    2014-03-03 00:02:01
```

My main issue is being able to project the resulting boolean series onto my original dataframe allowing me to segregate the results I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a potential solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CARD_NO','CUSTOMER_ID','MODIFIED_DATE','STATUS','LOYALTY'])

for name, group in input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False):

if len(group) == 1:
    #print group
    df = df.append(group)
else:
    dates = group['MODIFIED_DATE'].values #good
    if all_same(dates):
        #print group[group.STATUS == '1']
        df = df.append(group[group.STATUS == '1'])
    else:
        #print group[group.MODIFIED_DATE == most_recent(dates)]
        df = df.append(group[group.MODIFIED_DATE == most_recent(dates)])

print df
```

I'm afraid this may run poorly on my real dataset(~3million records).
I'm testing it right now but I'm not confident about it.
Perhaps there is a more Pandas-esque way to solve this? Avoiding the need for a 'for-loop' and the dynamic appends to a new dataframe?